# Adding var to new window Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

doing some HTML and javascript stuff and I seem to be at a stand still at this one spot.
All i have to do is perform a simple calculator and take the result and display it on a new window. Was using javascript to open the new window but having trouble taking the result and putting it into the new HTML window text box.

var totalarea is the value i need added to the new window was thinking of putting it in the HTMLstring+='

\n'; somewhere

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Cross-Window HTML</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function newPage() {
HTMLstring='<html>\n';
HTMLstring+='<head>\n';
HTMLstring+='<title>New Document</title>\n';
HTMLstring+='</head>\n';
HTMLstring+='<body>\n';
HTMLstring+='<p><input type="text" name="area" id="area"/> Is how much carpet you need                                   in feet.</p>\n';
HTMLstring+='</body>\n';
HTMLstring+='</html>';
newwindow=window.open();
newdocument=newwindow.document;
newdocument.write(HTMLstring);
newdocument.close();
}

function ComputeSquareFeet() {
var percent = .01;
var num1 = +document.getElementById("length").value;
var num2 = +document.getElementById("width").value;
var num3 = +document.getElementById("allowance").value;
var area = num1 * num2;
var totalarea = (num3 * percent * area) + area; 
}
function newfeetwin() {
ComputeSquareFeet()
newPage()
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Carpet Calculator</h1>
<form name="userInputs">
<label for="lengths">Enter the length of your room in feet</label><br/>
<input type="Text" name="length" id="length" size="7"><br/>

<label for="widths">Enter the width of your room in feet</label><br/>
<input name = "width" id="width" type="text"size="7"><br/>

<label for="allowance">Typically an allowance is made for room irregularities and         unavoidable waste.<br/>
Enter the percent overage as an integer in the interval [0, 20]</label><br/>
<input name = "allowance" id="allowance" type = "text" /><br/>


<input type="button" name="CalcSqFeet" id="area" value="Calculate Square Feet" onClick="newfeetwin()" /><br/>

<br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The function *ComputeSquareFeet* needs to return something to the caller (*totalarea* seems appropriate), then the call to *newPage* needs to include that value so it can be used inside the function, something like `...<input ... value="' + area + '" id="area">...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your functions like

```
function newPage(totalarea) {
HTMLstring='<html>\n';
HTMLstring+='<head>\n';
HTMLstring+='<title>New Document</title>\n';
HTMLstring+='</head>\n';
HTMLstring+='<body>\n';
HTMLstring+='<p><input type="text" name="area" id="area" value="'+totalarea+'"/> Is how much carpet you need                                   in feet.</p>\n';
HTMLstring+='</body>\n';
HTMLstring+='</html>';
newwindow=window.open();
newdocument=newwindow.document;
newdocument.write(HTMLstring);
newdocument.close();
}

function ComputeSquareFeet() {
var percent = .01;
var num1 = +document.getElementById("length").value;
var num2 = +document.getElementById("width").value;
var num3 = +document.getElementById("allowance").value;
var area = num1 * num2;
var totalarea = (num3 * percent * area) + area; 
return totalarea;
}
function newfeetwin() {
//ComputeSquareFeet()
newPage(ComputeSquareFeet())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the value from JavaScript function, Then pass value to answer box..
change you JavaScript code as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function newPage(dd) {
HTMLstring='<html>\n';
HTMLstring+='<head>\n';
HTMLstring+='<title>New Document</title>\n';
HTMLstring+='</head>\n';
HTMLstring+='<body>\n';
HTMLstring+='<p><input type="text" name="area" id="area" value="'+dd+'"/> Is how much carpet you need                                   in feet.</p>\n';
HTMLstring+='</body>\n';
HTMLstring+='</html>';
newwindow=window.open();
newdocument=newwindow.document;
newdocument.write(HTMLstring);
newdocument.close();
}

function ComputeSquareFeet() {
var percent = .01;
var num1 = +document.getElementById("length").value;
var num2 = +document.getElementById("width").value;
var num3 = +document.getElementById("allowance").value;
var area = num1 * num2;
var totalarea = (num3 * percent * area) + area; 
return totalarea;
}
function newfeetwin() {
    var dd = ComputeSquareFeet()
    newPage(dd);
}
</script>
```

i think you got what do you want..
cheers..